# Issue in building Converse.js on windows

Tags: node.js, converse.js

I am trying to build Converse.js on my Windows machine. I have installed all required pre-requisites as mentioned on the website. However i am getting issue while building a code. Can someone please help me with the steps to resolve?

Here is the issue

```
    D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(339): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(339): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(343): error C2039: 'ThrowException': is not a member of 'v8' (
compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(64): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(343): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(343): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(343): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(348): error C2039: 'ThrowException': is not a member of 'v8' (
compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(64): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(348): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(355): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(355): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(357): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(357): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(357): error C2660: 'v8::Integer::New': function does not take
1 arguments (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThread
s.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(369): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(369): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(373): error C2039: 'ThrowException': is not a member of 'v8' (
compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(64): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(373): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(373): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(373): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(377): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(377): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(381): error C2039: 'ThrowException': is not a member of 'v8' (
compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(64): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(381): error C2039: 'New': is not a member of 'v8::String' (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\v8.h(2443): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThrea
  ds.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(381): error C3861: 'New': identifier not found (compiling sour
ce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(381): error C3861: 'ThrowException': identifier not found (com
piling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(408): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::'
 must be a type (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerTh
reads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(408): error C2039: 'FreeCallback': is not a member of 'node' (
compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
  D:\Users\rphatak\.node-gyp\8.9.1\include\node\node_object_wrap.h(29): note: see declaration of 'node' (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorke
  rThreads.cc)
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(408): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FreeCallback' (co
mpiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(409): error C2065: 'callback': undeclared identifier (compilin
g source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(409): error C2065: 'hint': undeclared identifier (compiling so
urce file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-threads\node_modules\nan\nan.h(416): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New': none of the 4 overload
s could convert all the argument types (compiling source file ..\src\WebWorkerThreads.cc) [D:\SourceCode\converse.js\node_modules\webworker-th
reads\build\WebWorkerThreads.vcxproj]
```

I feel that this issue is coming due to incorrect versions of gyp. Here are the versions
Node - v8.9.1
NPM - 5.5.1
Node-gyp - 8.9.1
Do let me know the changes i need to do in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: Add version of node and npm too

Comment: Its already there in my post Node - v8.9.1 NPM - 5.5.1

Comment: @Himanshusharma any suggestions? I think its a version issue only. However which version should be used?

Comment: I can only help this time that . The last build of cinverse.js is at aug 8 . And node 8 was not release that time . like v8::String::New("test") is converted into NanSymbol("test") . Have to try to downgrade node . You can use `n` or `nvm` to switch between node version . Hope this help .

Comment: Hello.   Did anyone find a solution too this?

Comment: I could resolve issue....as @Himanshusharma mentioned, i tried with different versions of NodeJS and finally succeeded

Comment: @RajanPhatak add your finding as answer , if you get time . May be this helps other .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue. Issue was due to incompatible version of NodeJS. As @Himanshu sharma suggested in the reply, i checked last build of cinverse.js which was at aug 8' 17 and found the NodeJS releases before that. Once i installed the appropriate version of NodeJS, i could resolve issue. In my case, it worked with version node-v4.8.4-x64